# How to output an Excel *.xls file from classic ASP

Tags: excel, web-applications, asp-classic

I have a number of generated html tables that I need to output as an Excel file. The site is codded in classic ASP. Is this possible? Could it be done by somehow using the Open Office libraries?

---

EDIT: Thus far, I have tried some of the suggestions, but it seems to fail. Ideally, I want the user to be able to click a link that will begin the download of a .xls file. This code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%  option explicit

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AppendHeader "content-disposition", " filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Test Col 1</th>
        <th>Test Col 2</th>
        <th>Test Col 3</th>
        <th colspan="2">Test Col 4</th>
        <th>Test Col 6</th>
        <th>Test Col 7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

seems to fail when IE7 is used to get the page. IE says that it "cannot download excelTest.asp" and that "The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found."

Comment: There are comments towards the end of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/vsofficedeveloper/pages/Office-2007-Open-XML-MIME-Types.aspx

Comment: The only comments I see on that page are some additional notes indicating the changes that need to be done on the server for the mime-types to be supported. Are you saying that this is the piece I'm missing?

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if anyone could take a look,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383366/generating-excel-file-error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's AddHeader, not AppendHeader.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%  Option Explicit

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**
I've written a blog post about how to [generate Excel files in ASP Classic](http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/03/02/generate-excel-files-in-asp-classic/). It contains a rather useful piece of code to generate both xls and csv files.

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if anyone could take a look,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383366/generating-excel-file-error

Comment: Thanks, Kristof Neirynck!! This helped me figure out how to get IE to recognize the Excel file as download.

Answer (score 4):

MS made a COM library called Office Web Components to do this.  MSOWC.dll needs to be registered on the server.  It can create and manipulate office document files.

[How To Use the Spreadsheet Web Component with Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235883/EN-US/)

[Working with the Office Web Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198515(office.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can always just export the HTML table to an XLS document.  Excel does a pretty good job understanding HTML tables.

Another possiblitly is to export the HTML tables as a CSV or TSV file, but you would need to setup the formatting in your code.  This isn't too difficult to accomplish.

There's some classes in the Microsoft.Office.Interop that allow you to create an Excel file programatically, but I have always found them to be a little clumsy.  You can find a .NET version of [creating a spreadsheet here](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/Creating_Excel_From_VB_DOT_NET-197_209_329.html), which should be pretty easy to modify for classic ASP.

As for .NET, I've always liked [CarlosAG's Excel XML Writer Library](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/).  It has a nice generator so you can setup your Excel file, save it as an XML spreadsheet and it generates the code to do all the formatting and everything.  I know it's not classic ASP, but I thought that I would throw it out there.

---

With what you're trying above, try adding the header:

```
"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
```

See if that works.  Also, I always use this for the content type:

```
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

Comment: VBScript throws an error: 

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Response.AppendHeader'

Answer (score 0):

There's a 'cheap and dirty' trick that I have used... shhhh don't tell anyone. If you output tab delimited text and make the file name *.xls then Excel opens it without objection, question or warning. So just crank the data out into a text file with tab delimitation and you can open it with Excel or Open Office.

Comment: Actually Excel 2007 will pop a warning dialog if a file is in TSV format, but it's extension reads .xls

I don't know of any way to avoid this either.

Comment: make the text file CSV but give it a .csv extension.  Excel will open it with no message.

Comment: Two potential issues: (1) Microsoft Excel will trim leading spaces and zeroes; and (2) Microsoft Excel 2010 will present warning when opening the file. #1 can be solved by wrapping text with ="{cell-data}" (via: http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#CSVAndExcel)

Comment: When I wanted to do this I think I ended up using either DIF or SYLK format to avoid conversion prompts, but it had the downside that it expected the file to use the OEM code page.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the file to be downloaded (attachment) by the client in the http header:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AppendHeader "content-disposition", "attachment: filename=excelTest.xls"
```

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-prompt-a-save-as-dialog-for-an-accepted-mime-type.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I added Response.Buffer = False.  Try changing the code to the following.

Response.Buffer = False
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"

The only problem I have now is that when Excel opens the file I get the following message.

The file you are trying to open, 'FileName[1].xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

When you open the file the data all appears in separate columns, but the spreadsheet is all white, no borders between the cells.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

the XLS file is not a real Excel file. The code create an HTML file with .an xls extension. When you try open the XLS file with Notepad, you can see the HTML code.