# How can I programatically convert .xls and .csv files to .xlsx?

Tags: excel

Is there a programmatic solution to this that does not involve having Office on the server?

**Update:**
This solution will be deployed in a .Net shop, so for now PHP and Java approaches aren't on the table (though I was impressed with the libraries themselves).

We will be receiving documents in csv, .xls, and .xlsx formats that need to be parsed and their data shoved into a DB. We're planning on using the OpenXML SDK for all of the parsing goodness and want to operate over only one file type.

Comment: Do these questions help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486256/creating-excel-or-excel-compatible-spreadsheets-on-the-server-side-in-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642702/generating-nicely-formatted-excel-files-in-asp-net-without-having-excel-on-server

Comment: Best answer depends on the programming language intend to use or are familiar with. I'd mention them as well. It may also help of you tell a bit more about the context. Is it a client application? Swing? Or a webapplication? JSP/Servlet or PHP? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the **[Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)** for Java.

> HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format.
>
> XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

I've used it to read in a complete mix of `.xls` and `.xlsx` files, and I always output `.xlsx`.

For `.csv` files, import using the **[Super CSV library](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)** and export using the Apache POI library above.

> The main motivation for Super Csv is to be the best, fastest and most programmer friendly free CSV package for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Or use PHPExcel ( http://www.phpexcel.net ) if you want a PHP solution rather than java

Answer (score 1):

For csv files i would recommend a combination of http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/ to read the csv file into a datatable and EPPPLUS to use its .FromDataTable Method to convert it to an xlsx file.
I works great for me and is very fast.
For reading xls files there is no free Implementation that I know of :(

Answer (score 0):

and you can use  for parse columns.

```
 object columnValue = ws.Cells[i, ColIndex, i, ColIndex].Value; // get Specific cell.
```

---

**you can use below method for .csv, xlsx, .txt files.**

```
      public yourReturnType compute()
        {
            #region .XLSX Section

            if (FilePath.FullName.Contains(".xlsx") || FilePath.FullName.Contains(".xls"))
            {
                // Open and read the XlSX file.
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(FilePath))
                {
                    ExcelWorkbook wb = package.Workbook;  // Get the work book in the file
                    if (wb != null)
                    {
                        if (wb.Worksheets.Count > 0)
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.First();  // Get the first worksheet

                              yourParseCode(ws);
                        }
                    } // if End.
                } // using end.
            }
            #endregion

            #region .CSV Section
            if (FilePath.FullName.Contains(".csv") || FilePath.FullName.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                CSVParser c = new CSVParser(FilePath);
                DataTable dt = c.ReadCSVFile();

                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("temporary");
                    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

                    yourParseCode (ws);

                    ////pck.Save(); // no need to save this temporary sheet.
                }
            }
            #endregion
            return (yourReturnType );
        }
```