# How to read an excel(.xls) file like text?

Tags: java, excel, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to read an excel(.xls) file that i'm receiving.
Using the regular charsets like UTF-8, Cp1252, ISO-8859-1, UTF-16LE, none of these helped me, the characters are still malformed.

So i search ended up using [juniversalchardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/), it showed me that the charset was MacCyrillic, used MacCyrillic to read the file, but still the same weird outcome.

When i open the file on excel everything is fine, all the characters are fine, since its portuguese its filled whit Ç ~ and such. But opening whit notepad or trough java the file is all messed up.
But if open the file on my excel and then save it again like .txt it becomes readable

**My method to find the charset**

```
    public static void lerCharset(String fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[50000000];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    // (1)
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

    // (2)
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
        detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }
    // (3)
    detector.dataEnd();

    // (4)
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encoding != null) {
        System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
    }

    // (5)
    detector.reset();
    fis.close();
}
```

How can i discover the correct charset?
Should i try a different aproach? Like making my java re-save the excel and then start reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you're trying to read the excel file like a text file.

The challenge is that .xls files are actually binary files containing the text, formatting, sheet information, macro information, etc...

You'd either need to save the files as .csv (Either via Excel before running your program or through your program directly), upgrade them to .xlsx (which has numerous libraries that can read the file as an XML at that point) or use a library (such as [apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) [or anything similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)) or even query the data out using ADO.

Good luck and I hope that's what you were implying via your question.

Comment: Can i use apache POI to save this file as a .csv?
This excel is not formatted, it has 2 columns and the definitions are made on the line, really confusing but that's something i will have to deal

Comment: What do you mean "definitions are made on the line"?

Comment: the file has column A and B, inside the column A i have the "definitions" which should be columns and on B the values.
But i have like COLUM A ROW 14 -> DESCRIPTION 

COLUM B ROW 14 -> XXXX
COLUM B ROW 15 -> CONTINUATION OF XXXX

Comment: If I were you, I'd just either use Apache to open the file and take the data out or just query the file directly (here's one link that can show you how to do that: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/jdbc-database-tutorials/356-how-connect-excel-spreadsheet-using-jdbc-java.html ) or look online for other libraries... It truly depends on what you're trying to accomplish... Give it a try and come back and ask questions if you get stuck.... Just do some looking around... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837039/how-can-i-programatically-convert-xls-and-csv-files-to-xlsx

Answer (score -1):

## Code:

```
WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
WorkbookSettings.setEncoding("Cp1252");
```

Comment: It would change the charset of my file?
I'm sorry i feel that its kinda vague to understand.

Comment: Yes.  It changes the Excel file into a characterset that is known to be compatible with java import/export.