# Is there a way to create Excel files in C# using a template without using the interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, open-source

I am updating an internal application that creates excel files based on a template, and I would like to recreate that functionality without having to use the excel interop. Does anyone know of any open source projects that can do this? I was using ExcelLibrary, but it does not work with the template.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am only interested in solutions that are known to work with existing *.xlt or *.xltx templates. Solutions where this is unknown are not helpful. Those can be found all over the web.

Comment: This question has been asked here on SO thousands of times,take for example: [Please suggest ways to manipulate Excel spreadsheet without using Excel object as web server does not have MS office installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643860/please-suggest-ways-to-manipulate-excel-spreadsheet-without-using-excel-object-as)

Comment: I am specifically looking for a solution that allows the use of templates. This is the only reason I asked.

Comment: @Doc Brown The reason I am asking is because I don't want to spend several hours testing each of the dozens of libraries available. I am simply hoping that someone will have used one successfully with a template.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Excel interop?

Comment: @Paul: why do you have to deal with xlt directly, can't you just convert them to xsl once before using them?

Comment: @svick, because there are a ton of headaches I avoid without using it...

Comment: @Doc Brown That is a possibility. My concern is preserving a custom header consisting of an image. I'm going to try these suggestions and see if any work for what I need. Otherwise it's back to the interop I guess :/

Comment: @Paul, it's quite likely you will just replace them with another set of headaches :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [OpenXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from MS...

It is a free library that does NOT require office to be installed... you can read + write Office files including Excel and Word (Version 2007 and up...).

IF you need more features (like rendering to PDF etc.) and/or support for pre-2007 formats (like XLT) then you would need some 3rd-party library... not opensource... but take a look at [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) - it handles XLT, XLTX, XLTM etc. too - for example regarding support for XLTX + XLTM see http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/feature-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

We've used [OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) to generate Word documents. I'm sure you can generate Excel files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link, This library allows you to generate Excel Workbooks using XML, hope this help.

[CarlosAg Excel Xml Writer Library](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these libraries depending on whether you want to work with Excel 2003/2007 or 2010.

[NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

[koogra](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) from Microsoft.
Then you can use the [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/) project to get you started.
Does not work for legacy office documents (i.e. doc/xls) only the new ones like docx and xslx.

hint: a docx/xslx is really a zip file full of xml documents. just change the extension to zip.