# Generating Excel to classic asp app on Windows Server 2003 IIS6

Tags: excel, asp-classic

Looking for a decent way to create Excel files either via Classic ASP or via a .NET web service (or page) the Classic ASP app calls which writes out a file or a stream (optional) that the Classic ASP page can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to generate an excel file from ASP Classic:
[How to output an Excel *.xls file from classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440892/how-to-output-an-excel-xls-file-from-classic-asp)

Different alternatives for Excel output:
[Generating an Excel file in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net/)

Comment: both of these links provide great information with enough to help for the best approach in different situations