# File fetch from database using asp

Tags: asp-classic, download, content-type

I am storing some the binary data for some files in a database (yes, I know this can be a bad idea).  I am able to get the files out, with the correct content type, since I have stored it.  But I'm having trouble getting the file to the client with the right filename.  Right now I have the following code in a file called get_file.asp:

```
sSQL = "SELECT filename, contenttype, binarydata FROM new_attachment WHERE filename = '" & filename & "'"

oRs.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3

If Not oRs.EOF Then
    Response.ContentType = oRs(1)
    Response.BinaryWrite oRs(2)

End if
```

This will return files correctly, but with the filename of 'get_file.asp', instead of, say, 'myfile.txt'.  The url visited is `.../get_file.asp?filename=myfile.txt`.

Is there a way I could change the name of the file when the browsers prompts the user to save it somewhere?

Comment: I was dealing with a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440892/how-to-output-an-excel-xls-file-from-classic-asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send out the correct header:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YOURFILE.TXT"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Content-Disposition` header.

The header should look like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<name of file>
```

Side note: The way you are concatenating SQL is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you should be using parameters.