# Classic ASP XLS output with carriage return in cell

Tags: asp-classic, xls

I have a Classic ASP script that outputs an HTML table as an XLS file but have had no luck getting a carriage return/line feed to work within a single cell.

For testing I am using code based on Kristof's response to [How to output an Excel *.xls file from classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440892/how-to-output-an-excel-xls-file-from-classic-asp)

I've tried every method I know of for inserting a carriage return/line feed. My sample code is as follows:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%  Option Explicit
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Line1<br />Line2</td>
        <td><p>Line1</p>Line2</td>
        <td><div>Line1</div>Line2</td>
        <td>Line1<%=chr(10)%>Line2</td>
        <td>Line1<%=vbCR%>Line2</td>
        <td>Line1<%=vbLF%>Line2</td>
        <td>Line1<%=vbCRLF%>Line2</td>
        <td>Line1\rLine2</td>
        <td>Line1\nLine2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am opening the XLS in Excel 2010. The first 3 examples using HTML tags show the carriage return but split the data across 2 rows. The rest of the examples show the data on one line. Is there any way to populate an Excel field using Classic ASP with a carriage return without it splitting into multiple rows?

EDIT:

To clarify, I am trying to replicate the behavior of typing alt-enter within a cell in Excel. In the screenshot below you can see that the first 3 examples are splitting the data into two cells (rows 1 & 2) while the rest all appear on one line. I am trying to achieve two lines of text in one cell. Is there any other code I can use to insert a line break but keep the data in one cell?

[Excel Screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/gi4yeakjl/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there is some confusion between the display of mark-up and output of carriage returns in your code.

The markup display gives the appearance of carriage returns for the first three td's

[image]

and the fourth, sixth and seventh td's contain carriage returns in the html source

[image]

EDIT asp per comment and screenshot supplied

Add the following style to your page and you can see the first cell behaving as desired.

```
<style>
<!--table
br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
tr {vertical-align:top;}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: I was listing all of the code I've tried to render a line break within an Excel cell. None of the methods I've tried have worked. I've added a link to a screenshot for clarification. The first 3 examples with markup break the text onto a new line, but also into a new cell. I need the text to stay in the same cell.

Comment: That's perfect! Didn't have much hope for resolving this considering how dated the code is. THANKS!

Comment: No probs, classic asp just won't leave the stage - don't forget to vote it up ;-)