# How to open and view the XML structure of an Excel file?

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2013

I want to open the path xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml of an Excel file.

When I Google how to do this, an article asks me to rename the Excel file to .zip, and then unzip the file and check out the structure.

But even after I zip and unzip the Excel file, I don't find any such XML files in the extracted files. I find the .xlsx file alone.

Update:
Based on the answers provided, I have renamed the Excel file to .zip, without actually zipping it.
Then I have downloaded 7-zip software, which provides an option to open the .zip file when right-clicked. I can now see the XML structure of the Excel file in 7-zip.

Comment: Look into a nice zipfile tool like 7-zip (which is now very popular and dependable). This will let you have extract option on right-click context menu. Then you just extract to folder, and it does it all for you without renaming the original Excel file.

Comment: @marcomarc. Thank you, I have installed 7-zip and  used it to open the renamed file. I could see the XML structure of the Excel file.

Comment: No problem. Just to reiterate - you don't have to rename the file when using 7-Zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers and comments provided, I have renamed the Excel file to .zip, without actually zipping it.

Then I have downloaded 7-zip software, which provides an option to open the .zip file when right-clicked. I can now see the XML structure of the Excel file in 7-zip.

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

You just have to rename the file from .xlsx to .zip (without zipping it).

Then, you can unzip with any unzipper like 7zip or WinRar on Windows, and Unarchiver on Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as you said, I have renamed the file to xyz.zip. But, I am not sure how to unzip this file manually. When I right click it, I don't get any option to extract files/unzip it.

Comment: @LAKSHMI just saw your message, you guessed it right :)

Comment: You don't even have to rename the file if you just on unarchive it, that will do it