# How to export a HTML <table> to a Excel 97-2003 document

Tags: excel, asp-classic, export-to-excel

I'm making a classic ASP page that needs to export an table tag to an Excel 97-2003 document...  My problem is that every code that I find is written in PHP. I cannot use PHP because the company I work on uses only classic ASP (yeah, I know =P)...

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript/jquery if you want this in ASP?

Comment: First result on google: [How to output an Excel *.xls file from classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440892/how-to-output-an-excel-xls-file-from-classic-asp)