# How to change 'Save as Type ' to .xls of dialog box while exporting the html table to excel using jQuery in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
// If Internet Explorer
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, tableid + fileNo + ".xls");
}
else
    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

return (sa);
```

in above code,when dialog box is showing ,there is .xls not in save as type.
so please tell me how .xls save as type can be add in dropdown

Comment: I don't believe you can set the filetype options of the Save As dialog via JS.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in agreement with @RoryMcCrossan - client scripting cannot affect the browser's 'Save As' dialog box.

If you want users to see that file type, when a user clicks your hyperlink, it should make a request to the server. Then, on the server, you have to generate the .xls file (or filestream in memory) and send the response back using the application/vnd.ms-excel bit you mentioned in your header.

Here's what *that* looks like: ([SO answer using classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594928/1520850))